# Instruments says memory leak in decodeObjectForKey

Tags: memory, ios4

I am using a small class to persist user settings to disk. When I run the leaks tool it says that I am leaking memory in the assignments below. If I release them in dealloc, instruments shuts up but the app starts crashing (overreleased objects?)

```
    @synthesize location,address;

// Decode an object from an archive
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    //location & address are defined like 
    //@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString* location
    self.location = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"location"];
    self.address = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"address"];

    return self;
}

//If I uncomment below lines, Instruments is happy but the app immediately crashes (I am   guessing over released objects ?)
- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
/*
    [self.location release];
    [self.address release];
*/
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should release them in the dealloc.

The self.location means you are accessing a property via a (generated) property accessor.
You should instead either set them to nil, or release the ivars directly.

So, use [location release]; instead of [self.location release];

Or, alternatively, use self.location = nil;